# How to load button background image from different website in php using style attribute?

Tags: css, image, button

If I open a gif file (http:/www.adlogic.com.au/recruiter_skin/rubicor/jamesgall/template/myWebsite_def_templ/
roundbutton2.gif)from browser it's opening.

But if I add the same gif url in style it is not loading the gif.

This is the code

```
<button 
    style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(http:/www.adlogic.com.au/recruiter_skin/rubicor/jamesgall/template/myWebsite_def_templ/roundbutton2.gif) !important; 
           BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; 
           TEXT-ALIGN: center; 
           BORDER-LEFT: 0px; 
           PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; 
           TEXT-TRANSFORM: uppercase; 
           PADDING-LEFT: 0px; 
           WIDTH: 130px; 
           PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
           DISPLAY: block; 
           COLOR: #fff; 
           FONT-SIZE: 11px; 
           BORDER-TOP: 0px; 
           CURSOR: pointer; 
           FONT-WEIGHT: bold; 
           BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; 
           TEXT-DECORATION: none; 
           PADDING-TOP: 4px">Email to a Friend</button>
```

and i am using this gif in other domain.

Comment: I feel I should let you know a few things. Firstly, writing in capitals is NOT pretty! Secondly, you can make this much simpler by concatenating your CSS rules such as; instead of specifying each border 1 by 1 you can do border: 0; which will work for all 4 borders. You also don't need to specify "px" if the value is 0. Might make things a little easier to read

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a slash in the url of the image: `http://www...`

when you paste the image url into your browsers address bar, this won't make any trouble, as most browsers will insert the missing slash for your convenience. but it seems this doesn't happen for files referenced via css.

Comment: schellmax I am able to load the image now.Thanks a lot.